# Industrial Laser sound

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

I'm not sure what i'm looking for, it's a CRACK not a zzzzap or buzzzzzzzzaw

Is that like an arc welder spark? I'm looking through a ton of my samples, and I can't seem to find anything. The welding sounds I have are all kind of sustained burning sounds. Not really what I want. All I need is a single CRACK and I can't seem to think of the name. Any help is appreciated.

The final sound fx is literally going to be 200ms, so that's the kind of quick attack CRACK i'm talking about. I was trying to look up industrial laser cutters on youtube, but they all either have voiceover or music (what I was seeing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a sped-up gunshot? Or whip crack?

Answer (score 3):

maybe this library:

http://www.tonsturm.com/Soundpacks/files/Electricity.html

high quality stuff

Answer (score 2):

I reckon layer a couple together.. I'm thinking the "gun-shot, whip crack" (as mentioned above) and the welding sound enveloped with a big transient..

You want the high impact transient but the source bonding of electricity so layer the two. Also, make sure you use some really tight, small room reverb to place it in a space.

hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the sound of two arcs hitting each other in the air. That's where the fast "crack" sound comes from. Look for some library sounds of a Jacobs Ladder, they usually have several of these kinds of sounds. Also, I have used the sound of a very large electrical switch being thrown with good success.